# JavaScript Error?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Please tell me what is wrong in the following ?

If condition false I will receive an alert message, if true nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validcheck(){
        var CCode = document.getElementsByName('CustCode')[0].value;
        var CodeLenth = 4;
        var Actual = CCode.length;
        if (Actual == CodeLenth)
        {
                         alert('Code Ok');      
                         document.getElementById('CustName').value = CCode;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Code must be 4 Chars');
            }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying 'nothing will happen' when the condition is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if true nothing Happen.

Well, actually if the condition is true here is the line of code that will be executed:

```
document.getElementById('CustName').value = CCode;
```

This line of code attempts to find an element in your DOM with `id="CustName"` and tries to set its value. If such element is not found in your DOM, then `document.getElementById('CustName')` will return `null` and when you attempt to call `.value` on it you will get an error. So it's not exactly that nothing happens. You probably got an error. Did you look in your javascript console?

Comment: thanks for answer, if i type code instead of document.getElementById('CustName').value = CCode; alert('Code Ok') i will not received message Code ok if condition is ture

Comment: Or if the element with `id="CustName"` is found but it's a `div` or `span` then there will be no errors but nothing will really happen.

Comment: Then the condition is never true.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('CustName').innerHTML = CCode;
```

`.value` is used for form elements e.g. input. `.innerHTML` is used for block, inline and other elements e.g. div, span and much more.